# Binomial Coefficient Identity, Double Series, Floor Function

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I came across this (supposed) identity for *natural* numbers $m$ and $n$: $$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}{ \sum_{j=0}^{m}{ \left(-1 \right)^{\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor+j}2^{n-i}\binom{n-i+\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor}{j}\binom{n-i+\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor-j}{\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor}\binom{i}{m-j}}}= \left(-1 \right)^{m} \binom{2n+1}{2m+1} $$
and would like to prove it.

Cross posting from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214544/binomial-coefficient-identity-double-series-floor-function) after getting no replies.

I am trying to keep a certain tone to my work so I am looking for a **human**, non-analytic, combinatorial or algebraic proof to the above. To be more specific, I'd like to **avoid** using generating functions, calculus, complex numbers, trigonometric functions, chabyshev polynomials and induction; every other technique would do.

**Update #1:** tested to be true for $n,m \leq100$

**Update #2:** I would like to give the reason as to why I would like to avoid using the above techniques.  I am trying to generlize this [identity (12)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html): $$ \left(\sin \left(nx \right) \right)^{2}= \left(\sin \left(x \right) \right)^{2} \left(\sum_{m=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}{\left(-1 \right)^{m} \binom{n}{2m+1}} \left( \cos^{2}x\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}-m} \left( \sin^{2}x\right)^{m}\right)^{2}$$
for an odd *natural* number $n$ and a number $x$ to a **general field**, using the framework of [*Rational Trigonometry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry) and its [*Spread Polynomials*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry#Spread_polynomials). I want to show that the latter identity is essentially a polynomial or an "arithmetical" identity, meaning that it is independent of the framework of the classical trigonometric functions and the framework of complex numbers, and that the problem of proving said identity is essentially a (rather complicated) problem of arithmetic or of counting. In this endeavor, I would like to keep a "theme" of not invoking techniques which regard the classical trigonometric functions, complex numbers or calculus. The binomial coefficient identity I wanted to prove came up in the process of this work.

Comment: *"I'd like to avoid using generating functions, calculus, complex numbers, trigonometric functions, chabyshev polynomials and induction"* -- what is left then? Abacus?

Comment: _"...Abacus?"_ -- I wish! Please see the update to the OP which I'll post shortly. But seriously, I would like to use any binomial identities that can be proven with "counting arguments", recurrence, inclusion-exclusion, bijective arguments, coefficient extraction, Riordan arrays etc...

Comment: What's wrong with induction (and how is it different from recurrence)? That would be my first choice when faced with a trigonometric identity involving multiples of angles.

Comment: What is your rational formula for $\left(\sin\left(x+y\right)\right)^2$ ? Are tangents and cotangents (not squared) rational in your theory?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I guess that choosing recurrence over induction is a more "artistic" position. I found that avoiding using induction leads to more insight into the subject, which is important to me because Rational Trigonometry and its Spread Polynomials are new theories.

The book _Divine Proportions_ by Norman Wildberger is distibuted for free at researchgate.net: [Rational Trigonometry](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266738365_Divine_Proportions_Rational_Trigonometry_to_Universal_geometry)

Comment: @darijgrinberg there is an analogeous identity in rational trigonometry to the classic identity involving $\sin(x+y)$, and you can find it on page 217 (bottom) of _Divine Proportions_; also see pages 73 and 88-91. This analogeous identity is valid in the rational number field, but I have to think about if and how it generalizes to a general field.

For non-squared tangents and cotangents - there is an analog. See pages 114 (bottom) and 116 (top).

Answer (score 10):

Notice that
$$\binom{n-i+\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor}{j}\binom{n-i+\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor-j}{\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor} = \binom{n-i}{j}\binom{n-i+\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor}{\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor}.$$
This lets us easily sum up the terms depending on $j$:
$$\sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j  \binom{n-i}{j}  \binom{i}{m-j} = [x^m]\ (1-x)^{n-i}(1+x)^i = [x^{2m}]\ (1-x^2)^{n-i}(1+x^2)^i.$$
(We will see later why dealing with squares of $x$ is preferable.)

So, it remains to evaluate the following sum:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^{\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor} (2-2x^2)^{n-i} (1+x^2)^i
\binom{n-i+\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor}{\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor}.$$
Let $i=2s+t$ where $s=\lfloor \frac{i}{2} \rfloor$ and $t=i\bmod 2$. Then the sum becomes 
$$\sum_{s\geq 0} \sum_{t=0}^1 (-1)^{s} (2-2x^2)^{n-2s-t} (1+x^2)^{2s+t}
\binom{n-s-t}{s}$$
$$=\sum_{t=0}^1 \frac{(1+x^2)^{2n-t}}{(2-2x^2)^{n-t}} (-1)^{n-t} \sum_{s\geq 0} \binom{n-s-t}{s} \left(-\frac{4(1-x^2)^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\right)^{n-s-t}$$
$$(\star)\quad = \sum_{t=0}^1 \frac{(1+x^2)^{2n-t}}{(2-2x^2)^{n-t}} (-1)^{n-t} \frac{(1+x^2)^2}{4(x-x^3)}\Im\left( \frac{2(1-x^2)}{(I-x)^2}\right)^{n-t+1}$$
$$=\Im \sum_{t=0}^1 \frac{(1+x^2)^{2n-t+2}}{2x} (-1)^{n-t} (I-x)^{-2(n-t+1)}$$
$$=-\Im \sum_{t=0}^1 \frac{(1-Ix)^{2n-t+2}(1+Ix)^t}{2x}$$
$$=-\Im \frac{(1-Ix)^{2n+1}}{x},$$
where $I$ is the [imaginary unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) ($I^2 = -1$) and $\Im X$ denotes the imaginary part of $X$.

Now we are ready to take the coefficient of $x^{2m}$:
$$[x^{2m}]\ -\Im \frac{(1-Ix)^{2n+1}}{x} = -\Im \binom{2n+1}{2m+1} (-I)^{2m+1} = (-1)^m\binom{2n+1}{2m+1}$$
as expected.

---

**UPDATE.** To clarify step $(\star)$:
$$\sum_{p\geq 0} \binom{p}{r-p} u^p = \sum_{p\geq 0} [z^{r-p}]\ (1+z)^p u^p = [z^r]\ \sum_{p\geq 0} (z(1+z)u)^p $$
$$= [z^r]\ \frac{1}{1-z(1+z)u} =[z^r]\ \frac{1}{(z_1-z_2)z}\left(\frac{1}{1-z_1z}-\frac{1}{1-z_2z}\right) = \frac{z_1^{r+1}-z_2^{r+1}}{z_1-z_2},$$
where $z_{1,2} = \frac{u\pm\sqrt{u^2+4u}}{2}$ are the reciprocals of the zeros of $f(z)=1-z(1+z)u$, so that $f(z)=(1-z_1z)(1-z_2z)$. When $u^2+4u=-v^2$ like in the case $(\star)$, we further have
$$\frac{z_1^{r+1}-z_2^{r+1}}{z_1-z_2} = \frac{2}{v}\Im \left(\frac{u+Iv}{2}\right)^{r+1}.$$

Comment: $\mathfrak{I} = ?$

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I thought it's standard -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number Anyway, I've just added explanation to the text.

Comment: Ah! I was used to $\operatorname{Im}$ for imaginary part, but I don't like it that much (as the same notation is being used for images). I have never seen $\mathfrak{I}$.

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response as I wanted to make sure I understood every step. Your answer is very nice, and was made very clear with the update. Thank you. Unfortunately I was looking to avoid using complex numbers, and I'll explain why in an update to the OP and in a response to your comment above.

Comment: @Hellbound: Here you may think about complex numbers as $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$, i.e., polynomials over the field of rational numbers modulo the polynomial $x^2+1$. Is that better?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Unfortunately, no. The combinatorial identity I asked about comes up in the proof of another identity (see update #2 in the OP); this identity already has a proof when considering fields containing an element $r$ such that $r^2=-1$, and I believe this identity is also true over a general field. Naturally, I wouldn't consider using a quadratic extension of some field in this proof, and I also wanted to keep a "theme" of not using complex numbers anywhere at all, but this is, of course, a somewhat "artistic" choice, and maybe It's a petty matter, but that is what I want to achieve.